# Access config items in CodeIgniter routing file

Tags: routes, codeigniter-2

I need to access some config items within routes.php. The config file has been autoloaded. It seems like routes file is loading earlier in CI life cycle and mostly static. Is it still possible to do so?

Using constants may be an alternative. But I prefer configs in my scenario.

Can anyone please help me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$route[$this->config->item('cms')['admin']['folder']] = "project-cms/admin/index";
```

work for me

Comment: can't believe how this gonna work. $this context there!

Comment: just tried `var_dump($this->config);exit;` at first line of routes.php. Everything is ok, we have CI object at `routes`

Comment: You 're correct. It was a config item from a autoloaded custom config file that I need to load. When I manually load that config file in routes.php and access config item, it works fine. So the problem was autoloading not done when routes executed as I think.

Anyway, thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

for me, this solved the problem:

```
 $this->router;
```

`var_dump` it to see it's elements, if routes.php contains:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['anything'] = "anything";
```

so what i used:

```
$this->router->default_controller;
$this->router->routes['404_override'];
$this->router->routes['anything'];
```